# Как через phpmyadmin разрешить пользователю доступ к базе с нескольких ip-адресов

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

В настройках привилегий пользователя в поле можно выставить ip-адрес, с которого можно подключаться к базе. Каким образом через интерфейс phpmyadmin можно указать несколько (в моем случае - 2) ip-адреса, с которых можно подключаться к базе? **Только не используя таблицу хостов**! Т.е. в моем понимании есть вариант "Использовать текстовое поле" и в нем через запятую или еще как указать конкретные ip-адреса. Символ % использовать не вариант, т.к. мне не нужно открывать доступ на всю подсеть.
[image: Скриншот]

Если выбираю вариант "Использовать текстовое поле:" и в поле рядом задаю ip-адреса через запятую или пробел, то к базе подключения нет совсем. Если оставляю только 1 ip-адрес, то доступ с него есть. А как прописать здесь 2 ip-адреса? Создавать несколько пользователей для каждого айпишника тоже некрасиво.

Comment: *как прописать здесь 2 ip-адреса?* НИКАК. Адрес - это компонента полного имени пользователя. Она может быть либо адресом, либо шаблоном - но не списком.

Comment: А почему "не используя таблицу хостов" ? если ip преобразуются в имена (через хосты или через DNS) то как раз можно получить произвольные списки и это единственный путь. И подозреваю, что символ '%' работает как в like и тогда не обязательно выделать подсеть, если ip схожи, то % вполне может заменять всего 1 цифру (но конечно это надо проверить)

Comment: @Mike Для замены строго одного символа используется подчёркивание `_`. А процент `%` заменяет любое число любых символов. [MySQL 8.0 Reference Manual  /  ...  /  Specifying Account Names](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/account-names.html). Впрочем, использование подчёркивания в IP я живьём не видел, только в hostname...

Comment: @Mike таблицу хостов, насколько я понимаю, можно записать только ручками в my.cnf (или подобный). У меня же задача сделать это штатными средствами phpmyadmin без "специальных знаний" (хотя знания имеются, но, спустя время, имеют свойство забываться). Символом % я могу заменить любой октет в ip-адресе, что в моем случае не вариант. Чувствую, что так и придется создавать несколько одинаковых пользователей для разных айпишников :(

Comment: *придется создавать несколько одинаковых пользователей для разных айпишников* Если их два - иного варианта просто нет. Кроме весьма теоретического `'user'@'192.168.0._01'` для адресов 192.168.0.101 и 192.168.0.201 (192.168.0.001 скорее всего под шаблон не попадёт из-за удаления ведущих нулей - но это надо тестить). *можно записать только ручками в my.cnf (или подобный).* Вообще-то в hosts.

Comment: Кстати, если MySQL работает под Windows, а сеть бездоменная, то можно и lmhosts.

Comment: @Akina не, такая маска не подойдет. Создал 2 пользователя, буду пока так. Дальше будет видно. Спасибо.

Comment: Вообще "таблица хостов" должна вестись административно и вообще не касаться mysql. Раз он позволяет использовать имена хостов, значит он использует преобразование ip адресов в имена и практически наверняка использует для этого штатные средства ОС, которые в свою очередь используют системный файл hosts и службу DNS (см. "обратные зоны", PTR, in-addr.arpa). И да, разумеется это никакого отношения к phpmyadmin не имеет, потому что он лишь средство работы с MySQL и от него не зависит вообще ни чего. все диктуется самим MySQL и окружением в ОС